# Frameworks error "normal arm64 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler"

Tags: ios, objective-c, react-native

[image: parse error][image: error sections][image: Check errors]The following build commands failed:
        CompileC /Users/**/**/**/Xcode/DerivedData/project-cjnpkxskhmofvscoog9qaznbuqhvs/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphoneos/DoubleConversion.build/Objects-normal/arm64/DoubleConversion-dummy.o /Users/**/**/**/IO-iOS/ios/Pods/Target\ Support\ Files/DoubleConversion/DoubleConversion-dummy.m normal arm64 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
(1 failure)

### Tried

- npm install
- pod install
- react-native run-ios runs the application in the simulator without error.
- react-native run-ios --device "name of device" gives me errors

Failed every time, please help

Comment: Did you found any solution?

Comment: No luck with this?

Comment: Any solution for the issue?